# Breadcrumb in single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Breadcrumb in my html page. But the breadcrumb keeps appearing in a new line. How can I make it come next to the glyphicon?

This is the div section:

```
<div class="col-md-3 well pre-scrollable scroll-pane">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
            <ul class="breadcrumb list-unstyled">
                <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumb track by $index">
                    <a href="" ng-click="loadNodeBc($index)">{{crumb}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            <p>
                <ul ng-repeat="node in nodes" class="list-unstyled">
                    <li ng-repeat="value in node"><a href="" ng-click="loadNode(value)">{{value}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
```

How it looks now:

[image: how it looks]

There are unwanted spaces in the top and bottom. But I want the list to appear next to the glyphicon as if they are in a new line.

Comment: Could you please add also CSS, or maybe JSFiddle?

Comment: I have not used any css other than the twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some CSS `inline`. `<ul>` elements are automatically block-level elements. I believe that Bootstrap automatically adds glyphicons to be `display: inline-block` as well so it can apply with and margins to the icon.

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/3b1d1tnv/1/)

```
span.glyphicon-folder-close,
ul.breadcrumb {
    display: inline;
}


    <div class="col-md-3 well pre-scrollable scroll-pane"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>

    <ul class="breadcrumb list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="">node1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node4</a>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    .....
    .....
```

---

**Addition:**

Here's another way of doing it. Wrap the `span` and `ul` in it's own separate container so they float together. You have to remove the padding for the `ul.breadcrumb` as it's auto applied.

[Add containers fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b1d1tnv/3/)

```
ul.breadcrumb {
    padding: 0;
}

<div class="col-md-3 well pre-scrollable scroll-pane"> 
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
    <ul class="breadcrumb list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="">node1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node4</a>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
....
....
```

---

**Addition #3 (worked best for OP)**

Here's an even better way. Just use psuedo selector for the breadcrumb and remove the `span` altogether. Also remove the `<hr>` tag and add border to the breadcrumb itself

[Fiddle w/ psuedo](http://jsfiddle.net/3b1d1tnv/4/)

```
ul.breadcrumb {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.breadcrumb:before {
   position: absolute;
    content: '\e117';
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    left: -10px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

<div class="col-md-3 well pre-scrollable scroll-pane">   
    <ul class="breadcrumb list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="">node1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">node4</a>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: This works, but now , when there are more than 3 li items, they overlap each other creating overlays

Comment: Please check my edit in the question. Also I am planning to use only inline css so can you tell me how your 2nd answer is done?

Comment: Can u tell me the reason your are using xs instead of md in the containers for span and ul ?

Comment: The addition in your answer makes it worse. I removed the container class for the div enclosing `ul` and it works as I want it to. But the breadcrumb text now starts very close to the folder icon.

Comment: Yes this is better. But there is still a lot of unwanted space above the `hr`.

Comment: Check the EDIT 2 in answer

Comment: that's b/c it's an `<hr>` tag and has styles applied. remove that element and add `padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;` to the `ul` element

Comment: Yes that works as I wanted. Please refine your answer with the final edit so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It may be due to the parent div width is not enough for show all.